# Use L'Hospital's rule to find $ \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{ \tan\beta x - \beta \tan x}{\sin \beta x - \beta \sin x} \right) $

Tags: calculus, limits

Use L'Hopital's rule to find $ \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{ \tan\beta x - \beta \tan x}{\sin \beta x - \beta \sin x} \right) $ where $\beta $ is a non-zero constant and $\beta \ne \pm 1$.

I have applied L'Hospital's rule (twice) but it doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

I have tried writing in terms of sine and cosine but that didn't appear fruitful either.

I have verified numerically that the limit of this expression appears to be $-2$.

What am I missing?

Comment: You will need three iterations of the Hospital in this example. I would advocate using Maclaurin series instead.

Comment: As answers here have shown, one can take the rule as the first step in a proof that uses other techniques later on. This is a common feature of "do X this way" questions.

Comment: This is from a textbook exercise that comes before Maclaurin series are introduced, so we should attempt to solve using only L'Hopital's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan(\beta x)-\beta\tan(x)}{\sin(\beta x)-\beta\sin(x)}$$ yields an indeterminate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{0}{0}$ case. Hence $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan(\beta x)-\beta\tan(x)}{\sin(\beta x)-\beta\sin(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\tan(\beta x)-\beta\tan(x))}{\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(\beta x)-\beta\sin(x))}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\beta \sec^2(\beta x)-\beta \sec^2(x)}{\beta\cos(\beta x)-\beta\cos(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2(\beta x)}-\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}}{\cos(\beta x)-\cos(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos^2(x)-\cos^2(\beta x)}{\cos^2(x)\cos^2(\beta x)}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos(\beta x)-\cos(x)}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to0}-\frac{\cos(\beta x)+\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)\cos^2(\beta x)}=-\frac{\cos(0)+\cos(0)}{\cos^2(0)\cos^2(0)}=-2$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Using the rules of L'Hospital one times and simplifying we get
$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac {-\cos \left( \beta\,x \right) -\cos \left( x \right) }{
 \left( \cos \left( \beta\,x \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( \cos \left( 
x \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If the application of  L'Hospital's Rule is not mandatory,

$$F=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{ \tan\beta x - \beta \tan x}{\sin \beta x - \beta \sin x} \right)  =\dfrac{\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\tan\beta x-\beta x}{x^3}-\beta\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\tan x-x}{x^3}}{\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin\beta x-\beta x}{x^3}-\beta\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x-x}{x^3}}$$

Using  [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion),

$$F=\dfrac{\dfrac{\beta^3-\beta}3}{-\dfrac{\beta^3-\beta}6}=?\text{  if }\beta^3-\beta\ne0$$

Observe the condition in the question!